# gcc/mingw linker fails with "first defined here" when using boost and quantlib - is it my fault?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

After upgrading to gcc 4.8 on my Windows box, my code no longer builds, as the linker fails. There are 14 almost identical error messages, the first one is:

> [mingw]\local\lib/libQuantLib.a(normaldistribution.o):normaldistribution.cpp:(.data$_ZZN5boost4math6detail11erf_inv_impIeNS0_8policies6policyINS3_13promote_floatILb0EEENS3_14promote_doubleILb0EEENS3_14default_policyES9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_EEEET_RKSB_SD_RKT0_PKN4mpl_4int_ILi64EEEE1P[_ZZN5boost4math6detail11erf_inv_impIeNS0_8policies6policyINS3_13promote_floatILb0EEENS3_14promote_doubleILb0EEENS3_14default_policyES9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_EEEET_RKSB_SD_RKT0_PKN4mpl_4int_ILi64EEEE1P]+0x0): multiple definition of `long double boost::math::detail::erf_inv_imp, boost::math::policies::promote_double, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> >(long double const&, long double const&, boost::math::policies::policy, boost::math::policies::promote_double, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> const&, mpl_::int_<64> const*)::P'
>   .obj\Debug\margin-distrib.o:margin-distrib.cpp:(.rdata$_ZZN5boost4math6detail11erf_inv_impIeNS0_8policies6policyINS3_13promote_floatILb0EEENS3_14promote_doubleILb0EEENS3_14default_policyES9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_EEEET_RKSB_SD_RKT0_PKN4mpl_4int_ILi64EEEE1P[_ZZN5boost4math6detail11erf_inv_impIeNS0_8policies6policyINS3_13promote_floatILb0EEENS3_14promote_doubleILb0EEENS3_14default_policyES9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_EEEET_RKSB_SD_RKT0_PKN4mpl_4int_ILi64EEEE1P]+0x0): first defined here

and it all ends with

> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have found that I can "solve" this with the `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition` gcc option, but I have a feeling this only hides the problem. I would like to understand what is going on and, in particular, whether it is my fault.

Now, margin-distrib.cpp is using three distributions from boost::math, as does QuantLib's normaldistribution.cpp. It is therefore natural that both end up calling the same boost functions.
Since these boost libraries are header-only, it looks like those functions end up in both QuanLib's dll and my .o file, something the linker does not like.

Interestingly, this does not happen on Linux, where the code builds without problems - but this could because I am using older versions of both boost and quantlib there.

So, am I doing anything wrong, or is the problem in the libraries?

Comment: Are you sure that these boost libraries which *you and quantlib* use is *header-only*? Are you really sure to use no [built-required libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries)?

Comment: @ikh Yes. The only built boost library I use is `program_options`. I checked, and QuantLibs implementation of inverse normal cdf uses `boost::math::quantile` with `boost::math::normal_distribution`. In my `margin-distrib.cpp`, I use `boost::math::lognormal_distribution`, whose quantile function calls normal quantile - which calls `boost::math::erfc_inv` which calls `boost::math::erf_inv_imp` .. which explains why this turns out in both QuantLib.a and margin_distrib.o.

Comment: Hm, then...... try checking whether you're using the same version of boost with quantlib and whether these boost libraries have an option *creating a .o file which contain implements*. (Sometimes it is used to reduce compliation time - Boost.Asio has that option.)

Comment: @ikh I use the same version: I have just installed a new version of gcc and built first boost and then QuantLib with it. As for creating an .o file for header-only libraries, it does not sound like the normal way of doing things..